# Data not displaying in dynamic drop down list asp.net & C# (no errors too)

Tags: c#, asp.net

// aspx code

```
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataTextField="fullname" DataValueField="username" AutoPostBack="True" Width="125px" Height="22px"></asp:DropDownList>
```

// Code behind

```
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=xyz;Database=db;Uid=db;Pwd=12345");
 myConnection.Open();         
 SqlDataReader myReaderddl = null;
 SqlCommand myCommandddl = new SqlCommand("SELECT [username], [fullname] FROM [qa_users]", myConnection);
 myReaderddl = myCommandddl.ExecuteReader();
 myReaderddl.Read();
 ddlrep.DataSource = myReaderddl;                    
 ddlrep.DataValueField = "[username]";
 ddlrep.DataTextField = "[fullname]";
 ddlrep.DataBind();
 myReaderddl.Close();
```

Comment: Where in code are you putting this?  Page_Load?  Can you please provide markup describing DDL as well as context of code-behind?

Comment: Where/how did you define `ddlrep` ?

Comment: More information required. I tidied up your code for you

Comment: Yes I have this code in Page_Load event

Comment: is data present in the table also check it

Comment: actually ddlrep is dropdownlist Id. But it wont let me edit here.

Comment: Can you set a break point at the `SqlDataReader myReaderddl = myCommandddl.ExecuteReader();` to see if you get any data from the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but it should work.

```
using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=xyz;Database=db;Uid=db;Pwd=12345"))
{
    using (var myCommandddl = new SqlCommand("SELECT [username], [fullname] FROM [qa_users]", myConnection))
    {
        var table = new DataTable();

        using(var myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommandddl))
            myAdapter.Fill(table);

        ddlrep.DataSource = table;
        ddlrep.DataValueField = "username";
        ddlrep.DataTextField = "fullname";
        ddlrep.DataBind();
    }
}
```

There's a couple changes I made that you should note:

- Use of a USING statement.  This offers a number of benefits, such as automatically calling Dispose() on your IDisposable objects, regardless of whether an Exception is thrown.   In my opinion, it's a nice visual for showing when and where an object is being disposed.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx
- Not using a SqlDataRader directly, rather, use of the SqlDataAdapter to fill the table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879f39d8

Comment: This worked. im not sure what issue was. but worked fine. Thanks

Comment: I think the issue was trying to assign a SqlDataReader to the DataSource property.  The DataSource property expects an instance of IEnumerable, IListSource, IDataSource, or IHierarchicalDatasource.

Answer (score 0):

Update your codebehind to look like the following:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{

   SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=xyz;Database=db;Uid=db;Pwd=12345");
    try 
    {
       myConnection.Open();         
       SqlDataReader myReaderddl = null;
       SqlCommand myCommandddl = new SqlCommand("SELECT [username], [fullname] FROM [qa_users]", myConnection);
       myReaderddl = myCommandddl.ExecuteReader();
       if (myReaderddl.HasRows)
       {
          ddlrep.DataSource = myReaderddl;                    
          ddlrep.DataValueField = "username";
          ddlrep.DataTextField = "fullname";
          ddlrep.DataBind();
       }
    }
    finally 
    {
       if (myConnection != null)
       {
          myConnection.Close();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you break on myReaderddl = myCommanddl.ExecuteReader(), do you ever go into the if block?  Is data being returned?

Comment: data is pulled but its not binding to the drop down list

Comment: Torres:: still not displaying

Comment: Just for giggles, instead of doing the binding, if you were to replace the binding with: while(myReaderddl.Read()) { ddlRep.Items.Add(new ListItem(myReaderddl["fullname"], myReaderddl["username"]));}, does it work?  Does it iterate over anything?

Comment: either way its pulling data but not displaying.

Comment: I have a feeling something else may be causing your issue.  Could you provide more extensive code for what you're doing?  If the above is not working but you are pulling data, something else you are doing is clearing out your dropdownlist.

Comment: Its a form where management team can select the user and check activity for that particular user in a defined date range..
is that make sense??

Answer (score 0):

Your DropDownlist Should be like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlrep" runat="server" Width="200px" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

and In code behind, in pageload or in any methode

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=xyz;Database=db;Uid=db;Pwd=12345");
 myConnection.Open();         
 SqlCommand myCommandddl = new SqlCommand("SELECT username, fullname FROM qa_users", myConnection);
 SqlDataReader myReaderddl = myCommandddl.ExecuteReader();
 if(myReaderddl.HasRows)
 {
 ddlrep.DataSource = myReaderddl;                    
 ddlrep.DataValueField = "username";
 ddlrep.DataTextField = "fullname";
 ddlrep.DataBind();
 }
 myReaderddl.Close();
```

in the pageload put the code under this block

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
        }
```

Comment: if possible then debug it..and see its coming inside the if block or not...use the modified query remove Brackets..

Comment: I debugged, data is there but its not binding.

Comment: ok do one thing remove the dropdown list and paste the code what i mentioned for drop down..the first one.

Comment: I tried your previous code too. One thing is for sure its pulling data but its not displaying

Comment: SqlDataReader myReaderddl = null;SqlCommand myCommandddl = new SqlCommand("SELECT username, fullname FROM qa_users", myConnection);
                    myReaderddl = myCommandddl.ExecuteReader();
                    myReaderddl.Read();
                    if (myReaderddl.HasRows)
                    {
                        ddlrep.DataSource = myReaderddl;
                        ddlrep.DataValueField = "username";
                        ddlrep.DataTextField = "fullname";
                        ddlrep.DataBind();                        
                    }myReaderddl.Close();

Comment: no no not this one i am looking for the tag like <DropDownList ID="ddlrep"....></DropDownList>

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlrep" runat="server" Width="125px"></asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Let me build the new page and try this.

Comment: did you check?put the code behind  under if (!IsPostBack)
        { } block

Comment: I would recommend @joshuam's solution.

Comment: I think its an Issue with postback if we call the code from if(!IsPostBack){} block it should work fine

Comment: @user1442828 did you checked it..?

Answer (score 0):

This is some of my old code so it is not pretty ( I use EF these days), but try somehting like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [username], [fullname] FROM [qa_users]", myConnection);

cmd.Connection.Open();
SqlDataReader data_table = null;
data_table = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ddlrep.DataSource = data_table;
ddlrep.DataValueField = "username";
ddlrep.DataTextField = "fullname";
ddlrep.DataBind();
data_table.Close();
cmd.Connection.Close();
cmd.Connection.Dispose();
```

I pulled this from a working project so it *should* work.